# how to test locally Altostra project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, altostra

I used altostra to deploy my application to the cloud, and everything is working as expected, but I don’t know how to test my code locally. I’m using API Gateway -> Lambda stack:

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3CQB.jpg)

I have to deploy my changes to the dev env to test them, which is not ideal. Are there any better ways of local testing using altostra?

Answer (score 0):

In order to test your code locally, Altostra CLI provides two commands `alto invoke <function-name>` and `alto start-api`

Invoke command is helpful for invoking lambda functions that expect SNS or SQS events as payload

Start API command is helpful for invoking lambda functions that expect API Gateway payload (Your case) because you can use Postman or other clients to trigger them.

First, you need to compile or build your project, for that, use the `alto build` [command](https://docs.altostra.com/reference/CLI/commands/altostra-cli-build?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=comment&utm_campaign=local_testing)

```bash
alto build
```

After that run

```
alto start-api
```

After that, you will see a list of localhost endpoints for your project

Note that for this command to work, you need docker and sam CLI installed

You can also check out this [blog](https://altostra.com/blog/altostra-localstack-workflow?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=comment&utm_campaign=local_testing) post about advanced local testing